# Is there a way to change file name local.settings.json in Azure Functions to a different name

Tags: spring-boot, azure-functions, maven-3

Please let me know if there is a way to customize Azure functions file name local.settings.json to a different name.

Comment: you are aware, that this file is only for local debugging, correct? If so, why do you need to change it?

Comment: agree. assume you want to deploy in azure. which file holds and how do we invoke that file? I am expecting an answer for the same.

Comment: When hosted in azure the settings are stored in the Azure Functions runtime/App Service and injected as environment variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer myself. local.settings.json is just for local usage but in production, these values have to be populated in Application settings. Refer  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings#settings

Answer (score 0):

`local.setting.json` is the default file. But you still can use a different file to configure your functions.

Solution is `Dependency Injection`. With this technique, you can use the file you want instead of using the default local.settings.json file. Customize a json file, and then load the configuration in the custom file in the startup class. For more information, have a look of this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection).